# Select sentence mysql java?

Tags: java, mysql, database

I've got a problem with the lists below, i need that the select searchs the id and print the objects, i know that im doing something wrong but how can i fix it? Should i left the while or the for?

```
String query = "SELECT id, fecha, folio FROM capacitacion.pedido WHERE id = ?"; 

PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(query);   
s.setInt(1, obj.getId());

ResultSet resultado = s.executeQuery(); 

while(resultado.next()){
    for(PedidoDetalleDTO detalle : obj.getPedidoDetalle()) {
        dto.getId();
        dto.getFecha();
        dto.getTotal();
        dto.getFolio();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your code correct? Why are you getting things inside something used to retrive data from the results? Why you used a for inside a while?

Comment: i juts putted because i dont what should i use, for or while, i dont know what's the correct way

Comment: It doesn't appear to me that you are using the result set objects and instead are deferring to another function `getPedidoDetalle()`

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstood how to use ResultSet. Just an EXAMPLE (not your real code):

```
String query = "SELECT id, fecha, folio FROM capacitacion.pedido WHERE id = ?"; 

PreparedStatement s = con.prepareStatement(query);   
s.setInt(1, obj.getId());

List<Foo> fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();

ResultSet resultado = s.executeQuery(); 

while(resultado.next()){  
    Foo f = new Foo();
    f.setId( resultado.getInt( "id" ) );
    f.setFecha( resultado.getString( "fecha" ) );
    fooList.add( f );
}

for ( Foo f : fooList ) {
    System.out.println( f.getId() + " " + f.getFecha() );
}
```